# WCF picking basicHttpBinding & ignoring the defined customBindings

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="httpBinding">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            <binding name="httpsBinding">
                <binaryMessageEncoding/>
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyNamespace.MyIService" behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.MyIService" >

            <endpoint address="http://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
                      binding="customBinding" contract="MyNamespace.MyIService"
                      name="httpBinding"/>
            <endpoint address="https://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
                      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding"
                      contract="MyNamespace.MyIService" name="httpsBinding" />               
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyNamespace.MyIService" >
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
                      binding="customBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="httpBinding"
                      contract="MyNamespace.MyIService"
                      name="httpBinding" />

        <endpoint address="https://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding"
                  contract="MyNamespace.MyIService"
                  name="httpsBinding" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have the above configuration in a WCF service that is hosted in IIS. I can successfully browse to the service in the browser, as you can observer i want to use a customBinding.

When i use visual studio to add a reference to this service in my client application using VS inbuilt add service reference dialogue,  below is the client endpoint that visual studio creates for me.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService"
        contract="ServiceReference1.MyIService" name="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What i'm not understanding is why VS is creating for me a client basicHttpBinding yet i have defined a customBinding on the server.

Also, when i test my service in "WCF Test Client" and then double click the config file in WCF Test Client, i see that indeed it displays the below config in the Test Client.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://myPCHostName/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService"
                contract="MyIService" name="BasicHttpBinding_MyIService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm sort of new to this WCF development & i'm not clearly understanding how my customBinding are being ignored.

From my config above, is BasicHttpBinding being set any where as the default binding, or is there away i can completely remove it even though i can't seem to figure where its being set from in that configuration.

Comment: `basicHttpBinding` is the default, out of the box binding for services that do not have an explicit binding configuration to use.  You can either do as Mimas says below, or define a "default" binding configuration by omitting the `name` attribute in the configuration.

Comment: Is this solved? Because I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to specify **behaviorConfiguration** and **bindingConfiguration** for both endpoints on service side. You have specified **bindingConfiguration** only for https endpoint, and have not done this for behaviors at all.

Should be something like

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding">
            <binaryMessageEncoding />
            <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="httpsBinding">
            <binaryMessageEncoding/>
            <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyIService" behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.MyIService" >
        <endpoint address="http://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" 
            contract="MyNamespace.MyIService" 
            bindingConfiguration="httpBinding" 
            behaviorConfiguration="httpEndpoint" 
            name="httpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="https://wcf-client-url/virtualDirectory/MyService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" 
            behaviorConfiguration="httpEndpoint"
            contract="MyNamespace.MyIService" 
            name="httpsBinding" />               
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpEndpoint" >
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```